# If $X_1=X_2$ on $B\in \mathcal{F}$, then $E(X_1)|\mathcal{F})= E(X_2)|\mathcal{F})$ a.s on $B$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

The theorem below is from Durret's Probability Theory and Example. My question is how does one get to the last inequality in the proof. My thinking is that $P(B)>0$ othherwise we don't have to consider it. Then $\int_{A\cap  B}Y_1-Y_2dP\geq \epsilon P(A)$ holds if we consider $\epsilon$ small enough?

[image]

Comment: Durret wants to show $Y_1=Y_2$ a.s. on $B\,.$ He should have taken $A=\{Y_1-Y_2\ge\epsilon\}\cap B\,.$ Showing that this set has probability zero is enough and that's what this proof shows.

Comment: @KurtG. So a typo then?

Comment: However you want to call this. What is more important is if Durret's or my version of the proof looks more convincing to you. What would be even better than that is if you tried to find your own.

Comment: @KurtG. Yours makes perfect sense to me!

Comment: You can google in the internet quite a few pdfs that list Durrett's errata. This one I did not find. Books like that have the advantage that they make us learn instead of believing everything we read in print.